# Resolve function argument type during invocation

Tags: typescript

```
const func = <T>(
  obj: T,
  attr: keyof T,
  arr: T[typeof attr][],
) => {
}

const obj = {foo: 1, bar: true};

func(obj, 'foo', [1]);
func(obj, 'bar', [1]); // shouln't be ok
func(obj, 'foo', [true]); // shouln't be ok
func(obj, 'bar', [true]);
```

How do I need `arr` argument type to be defined so that TS would correctly resolve its type during `func` invocation so that it wouldn't always be `number | boolean` but rather depend on actual `attr`?

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKgPgBQBQMMIARgFYBcMWANETAIZRQBO1A1gKYCeIcNesUat2NANpQeABy78mLVgF1xS+gEo0OGAG8CAXwIFQkWGXJpdcECGoBGWjFIjqbBF30BuI4mR5zjgDk1iCBjuJ2SurevsD+FEHOrGEwEVGeMAD0mTAQABYgCAA2YIGwpFwkHASx8eRBISmSrO7pWTn5hSVlTpUg1bUBMIFJTW5c6UA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it by ensuring you're getting the specific type of the property identified by the key by making the key type generic as well as the object type:

```
const func = <ObjectType, KeyType extends keyof ObjectType>(
    obj: ObjectType,
    attr: KeyType,
    arr: ObjectType[KeyType][],
) => {
    console.log(obj, attr, arr);
};

const obj = {foo: 1, bar: true};

func(obj, "foo", [1]);
func(obj, "bar", [1]);    // <== Error as desired
func(obj, "foo", [true]); // <== Error as desired
func(obj, "bar", [true]);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeA8gIwFYCmwUAKgJ4AOBANDANIFnlUwEAeUBYAJhDANaMQcGLkLFmBAHwAKAFAxFMEPgBco-EVKUaCpQEMoUAE7qGTHdT2L9x0xvHaqAbXOSAus-dWAlGikwAN7WMKCQIAA2BAB0ESAA5jIqeLSGJql2PgDccgC+OXJh0Mr4aEFwICDqAIy0OLbqJggE+XJyiMhJ+LQARBUgPbTO1e7Z7UjAXSkwPfXGgzDDo1lKMAD0a5io6ACidiDGMPp83AQQAJbGBNzjncm9-QvOTQTL65sY2zB7xgdHJ2dLtdbpN7jM5k8XssgA)